# How To Make VB.Net Form Invisible

Tags: vb.net, forms, opacity

I am using VB.Net and I'd like to ask how could I make my form invisible while the other objects on it are visible? When I set the form's opacity property into 0%, the objects on it are affected. Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TransparencyKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) of the form. You can set the forms back color, then set that as the transparency key and only the back color will become transparent. It will make the form transparent except the controls.

Like this:

```
Public Sub InitializeMyForm()
    BackColor = Color.Red
    ' Make the background color of form display transparently.
    TransparencyKey = BackColor
End Sub 'InitializeMyForm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, is there any way to move the form when you drag it on other location?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this but theres many examples on the internet showing how it could be do.

Try this method http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=396385

Comment: have you tried using that code?
the code doesn't work on me... :(